# Ways to distribute different toys and indistinguishable marbles among 3 people

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find the number of ways in which $4$ different toys and $5$ indistinguishable marbles can be distributed between $3$ people if each person receives at least $1$ toy and $1$ marble.

Answer (score 2):

The $5$ indistinguishable marbles can be distributed in $6$ ways as follows: Give each person a single marble then you have $2$ marbles left. Now either $1$ of the person can get $2$ of these marbles in $3$ ways or you can give $2$ people $1$ marble each in $3$ ways so the marbles can be distributed in $6$ ways.

Then to distribute the toys I can choose $1$ person who will get $2$ toys in $^3C_1$ ways. Now I can choose $2$ toys to give out of $4$ in $^4C_2$ ways. Now that $2$ children can get remaining toys in $2$ ways

So we get the answer as

> $ 6×2×^3C_1×^4C_2 = 216 $